# Slide up element fade in using jQuery without affecting dom

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to add a slide up effect to an element when it fades in. I would use CSS3 transitions but I need to support IE9.

The method i'm using is to animate margin-top from `20px` to `0px` as the element fades in.

My problem is that this obviously affects the content below the element in the DOM. Is there a way to do this so that the content below the element isn't affected?

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".fade-in-block").css({opacity : 0, marginTop : "20px"})
                    .delay(100)
                    .animate({
                        marginTop : "0px", 
                        opacity : 1
                    }, 500, 'linear');
  });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg8e3j8s/)

Comment: Wrap it in an element that keeps the space open even if the block moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the div's position to relative and then animate `top` instead of `margin-top`.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg8e3j8s/1/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(".fade-in-block") .css({opacity : 0, top : "50px" })
        .delay(100)
        .animate({
            top : "0px",
            opacity : 1
        },  500, 'linear');
      });

});
```

```css
.button {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fade-in-block {
    min-height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
}

.not-fade-in-block {
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">click me</div>
<div class="fade-in-block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<div class="not-fade-in-block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```